# Multiple Depots 1 Line

Tags: cities-in-motion-2

In Cities in Motion 2, I have a line with more buses than the largest limit of a bus depot.

How can I add another depot to a line so that buses can use that for servicing too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now (and it seems quite likely for a while) no, you can't, but there are things you can do:

> -You can make the schedule so that there are enough buses continually running all through the night, so that they don't return and overload
>   the depot.
>
> -You can make a long road to the depot so buses that don't fit in will just sit on the road leading to the depot.
>
> -For Future games, use the custom ruleset feature and increase depot repair capacity.

Full credit goes to C40LFR for his post [here](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?794045-Multiple-Depots-1-Line&p=17838865&viewfull=1#post17838865).

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you can build a second depot nearby (or anywhere i guess) and when your vehicles start to degrade and run slower etc,transfer them to the 2nd depot for repairs. (Click on the little green house on the vehicles panel...It would probably be a good idea to make sure they are empty 1st), When they are repaired,switch them back to the 1st depot. ...I would like to know how to add the 2nd depot to a line, (or 3 or 4 for that matter) When i built the 2nd depot,it said something like "this depot is not attached to a line"...I must be going blind in my old age,tried to do it for about 2 hours last night....nothing worked! anyway,that's my 2 cents worth lol

Comment: This appears to be somewhat of an answer but also seems to be reiterating and trashing the question. As this is a question and answer site and not a discussion forum you should really [edit] this to focus more on the answer side of your answer.